# getting all mysql results that is less than given id

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on a timeline for my website but i am having some problem when i ran the query to select all id that is less than given identifier its still return the identifier result upon every query 
example if identifier is id=4 i want to select everything less than 4 and not from 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 i want it to be 3 > 2 > 1

here is my php. i know its not secure or what not but i have written it in prepared statement and get the same thign so i need some here.

```
if(isSet($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
    $feed_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastmsg']);
    $get1 = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT receiver FROM connection where sender="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"');
    $id_feed = array();
    while($id_result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($get1)){
    $id_feed[] = $id_result1['receiver'];
    $ids1 = join(',', $id_feed); 
    $get_feed1 = mysqli_query ($con, "select * from feed where users in '".$ids1."' or users='".$_SESSION['userid']."' and 'feed_id' < '".$feed_id."'  ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 2");

    }

    while($res1 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_feed1)){ 
    echo $load = $res1['feed_id'];


    }

    }
```

Comment: Your quotes are wrong. Column names should be enclosed in backticks `\``.

Comment: I'm almost willing to bet that the reason you're getting `4` is because of `or users=`. Since you're using `OR` it will include it regardless of the condition afterwards.

Comment: you are so right Patrick i remove that and it works. but i want to include result with the session users how can i include that also

Comment: Use parenthesis, `where(users in....or users=...)`